# Login & Access Classes?

Tags: java, authentication

I've been learning Java for the past few weeks and I've like to add better security to my script. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is to have a user login using some forum credentials. After they login they get access to a few java .classes hosted online which they can run but not download.

I'm not asking for codes or snippets, just a better insight on how I could accomplish this.
ie. Links to some useful Java Docs for what I need.

I've been searching Stackoverflow but pretty much have gotten lost/confused with the difference topics.

All help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "using some forum credentials"?  Do you want to login using credentials of a thirdy-party site or, more simply, do you want to learn how to implement a login for your forum application?

Comment: @Pino I want to be able to add a login to my application using an account from a forum I host. If the login is good then they have access to a .class file hosted online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've only been doing this for the past few weeks, then don't even try to accomplish this. To setup a truly secure enviroment requires a lot of experience. If you really want to try though, you should be looking at webservices.

As Karthik Ramachandran stated in [his answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874507/secure-java-web-services), you should always keeping in mind:

> First secure the transport using SSL. If you control both the clients
>   and the server then you can require 2-way SSL which would ensure that
>   only trusted clients can connect.
>
> Second you can implement WS security protocols. Web service security
>   standards tend to deal with three things: Authentication, Digital
>   Signatures and Encyption/Decyption (from the Spring-WS docs):
>
> Authentication. This is the process of determining whether a principal
>   is who they claim to be. In this context, a "principal" generally
>   means a user, device or some other system which can perform an action
>   in your application.
>
> Digital signatures. The digital signature of a message is a piece of
>   information based on both the document and the signer's private key.
>   It is created through the use of a hash function and a private signing
>   function (encrypting with the signer's private key).
>
> Encryption and Decryption. Encryption is the process of transforming
>   data into a form that is impossible to read without the appropriate
>   key. It is mainly used to keep information hidden from anyone for whom
>   it is not intended. Decryption is the reverse of encryption; it is the
>   process of transforming of encrypted data back into an readable form.
>
> There are a number of protocols/standards for each of these functions,
>   and there are a number of Java OSS projects that implement the various
>   security protocols/standards in a reasonable, usable ways.
>
> In particular I'd look at Sun's XWSS and APACHE WSS4J. Spring WS has
>   implementations of both of these APIs, they also do a good job of
>   describing the various components:
>   http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/security.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't really think I need encryption though. Just a simple way of login in using forum credentials and from there gain access to java classes hosted online.